# What do I need to know about 3D TVs for gaming?

Tags: monitor, stereo-3d

Recently I heard that the PS3 supported HDTV. I was confused and looked it up. I found [this which talks about adding support to Blu-ray movies](http://news.cnet.com/8301-17938_105-20017116-1.html). But the context I heard it was about it being in games.

Also, there are dozens of 3D TVs. Is there some kind of standard (will there be a format war)? Will the PS3 work on all 3D TVs or some? Are games supported or not? Do I only need to worry about the glasses matching the TV or is there more to do with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3D TVs now coming out all support the HDMI 1.4 (or better) 3D standard, which is what the PS3 and other 3D blu-ray devices support.

So yes, you will be able to mix and match 3D equipment from the player, to the cable, to the TV.

The glasses are not standardized yet, though, so you will likely need to make sure that any extra pairs of glasses you purchase are compatible with your 3D TV.

Game support is spotty - games need to be developed that support it, or be patched to support it.  [There are many sources for information](http://www.google.com/search?q=3d+ps3+games) on what games are currently or will be supported for 3D displays, [here is one list from December 2010](http://blog.us.playstation.com/2010/12/20/stereoscopic-3d-on-the-ps3-full-list-of-all-3d-games-and-blu-rays/).

Comment: One additional question. Do all 3d tvs that use hdmi support hdmi 1.4? there cant be a tv that has hdmi and NOT support 1.4 but its own proprietary version? I dont actively need to check if the tv supports 1.4 when i know its 1080p and is 3d? -edit- maybe you can mention a gotcha if there are any? I still remember the confusion between HD ready vs not

Comment: @acidzombie24 You don't need to check.  If the TV is new (ie, released in 2010 or later), supports 3D, then it supports the standard.  There are some older attempts at 3D (such as nVidia's 3D gaming monitors released a few years ago) that followed proprietary standards or weren't fully tested against HDMI 1.4, but newer TVs released in 2010 and later all follow and are tested to the same standard.